# how to store meta data in mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Im confused about storing meta data abt other tables in the database.

I have tables: goals, comments etc where users can insert data. And i need to store description abt each of these tables and how many rows can be inserted per person per table.

For example,

```
goals -> a description field, a count field
comments-> description field only
rating -> description field, weight field
```

My doubt is, in such cases **is it better to keep a central table that store all such information** (without thinking of normalization). **Or create separate meta table for each of the tables**, like, comment_settings, goal_settings, rating_settings?

Im doing this in cakePHP. I dont wish to be a purist but i dont feel good abt ruining the MVC paradigm or messing with performance without doing normalizing. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use JSON to encode the data into a string before insertion into a text field.  This does have significant flexibility advantages, but has probably just as many convenience implications as well, such as being able to index on a value.

It might be possible to overcome some JSON issues by using something like : http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_json/index.php

However you should have a play and see what fits best for your needs.

Personally I prefer the :

`Variable varchar(20), Value varchar(255)` - type of data structure for example :

```
Variable : GoalsDesc1
Value    : This is a description of a goal
Variable : GoalsCount1
Value    : 2


Variable : Comments1
Value    : This is a comment field
```